# Edit Text´s default text

Tags: android

How can I set a default text in an EditText of android. But I want only an informative text not editable, and when you click in the edit text you can write all you want without having to delete this text.

I want text that is present when the EditText is still empty, but disappears as soon as the user starts to type something.

Thank you.

Comment: `android:text="Some Text"` in xml then use `myEditText.append("Some more Text)` [append](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Do you want to append the text with a new text or completley replace a text with other???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `hint` property for the edittext like this

```
android:hint="Email"
```

It sets a Hint text to display when the text is empty.

Comment: Happy that you got it.. :)